# Assign value from match statement

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a Git command in Rust. I'm using the `clap` argument parser crate to do the command line handling. I want my command to take an optional argument for which directory to do work in. If the command does not receive the option it assumes the users home directory.

I know that I can use the `std::env::home_dir` function to get the user's home directory if it is set but the part that confuses me is how to properly use the `match` operator to get the value of the path. Here is what I've been trying:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    // Do some argument parsing stuff...

    let some_dir = if matches.is_present("some_dir") {
        matches.value_of("some_dir").unwrap()
    } else {
        match env::home_dir() {
            Some(path) => path.to_str(),
            None       => panic!("Uh, oh!"),
        }
    };

    // Do more things
```

I get an error message when I try to compile this saying that `path.to_str()` doesn't live long enough. I get that the value returned from `to_str` lives for the length of the `match` scope but how can you return a value from a match statement that has to call another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path.to_str()` will return a `&str` reference to the inner string contained in `path`, which will only live as long as `path`, that is inside the `match` arm.
You can use [`to_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_owned) to get an owned copy of that `&str`. You will have to adapt the value from `clap` accordingly to have the same types in both branches of your if:

```
let some_dir = if matches.is_present("some_dir") {
    matches.value_of("some_dir").unwrap().to_owned()
} else {
    match env::home_dir() {
        Some(path) => path.to_str().unwrap().to_owned(),
        None       => panic!("Uh, oh!"),
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could use `Cow` to avoid the copy in the first branch:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

let some_dir: Cow<str> = if matches.is_present("some_dir") {
    matches.value_of("some_dir").unwrap().into()
} else {
    match env::home_dir() {
        Some(path) => path.to_str().unwrap().to_owned().into(),
        None       => panic!("Uh, oh!"),
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the scope of the match statement takes ownership of the `PathBuf` object returned from `env::home_dir()`. You then attempt to return a reference to that object, but the object ceases to exist immediately.

The solution is to return `PathBuf` rather than a reference to it (or convert it to a String and return that instead, in any case, it has to be some type that owns the data). You may have to change what `matches.value_of("some_dir").unwrap()` returns so that both branches return the same type.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather simple trick: increase the scope of `path` (and thus its lifetime) so that you can take a reference into it.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    // Do some argument parsing stuff...

    let path; // <--

    let some_dir = if matches.is_present("some_dir") {
        matches.value_of("some_dir").unwrap()
    } else {
        match env::home_dir() {
            Some(p)    => { path = p; path.to_str().unwrap() },
            None       => panic!("Uh, oh!"),
        }
    };

    // Do more things
}
```

It is efficient, as `path` is only ever used when necessary, and does not require changing the types in the program.

*Note: I added an `.unwrap()` after `.to_str()` because `.to_str()` returns an `Option`. And do note that the reason it returns an `Option<&str>` is because not all paths are valid UTF-8 sequences. You might want to stick to `Path`/`PathBuf`.*

Comment: I did actually end up converting the string to a PathBuf object so that I could modify the path as you advised.